# Permalink rewrite with custom post type and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I think thats a quick one:

I've got:

1. Custom post type: **Food**
2. Custom taxonomy (Registered to Food): **Fruits**
3. Terms in **Fruits**: **Apple**, **Orange**, **Cherry**

If I type in ***example.com/food?fruits=Apple,Cherry***, I get all posts in **Fruits** with the terms **Apple** and **Cherry**, thats great!

But I would like to type in ***example.com/food/fruits/Apple,Cherry*** or ***example.com/food/Apple,Cherry*** to get the same result.

I´ve tried different permalink and rewrite plugins related to custom posts but nothing helped.

Thank you,

David

Comment: Similar implementation can be found here.
**http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/custom-taxonomy-specific-to-a-custom-post-type**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build up the link structure by using filters `post_link` and `post_type_link`:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'territorio_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'territorio_permalink', 10, 3);

function territorio_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
if (strpos($permalink, '%territorio%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

// Get post
$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) return $permalink;

// Get taxonomy terms
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'territorio','orderby=term_order');
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
$taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug.'/'.$terms[1]->slug; //build here
else $taxonomy_slug = 'not-yet';

return str_replace('%territorio%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

Where `hotel` is the post type and `territorio` is a hierarchical taxonomy.

In post type creation use:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'anything-you-want/%territorio%','with_front' => false),
```

Note: if you want deeper links, your build should go deeper:

```
$taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug.'/'.$terms[1]->slug.'/'.$terms[2]->slug;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works pretty well! But I have another custom post type which is using the same taxonomy and I always get posts of both categories.

Comment: not categories but **custom post types**

Comment: I get the same posts by typing example.com/food/fruits/Apple,Cherry or example.com/meal/fruits/Apple,Cherry, I think wordpress no more care about the /food or /meal.

Comment: I'm not into sharing taxonomies, as we talked here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55055/two-custom-post-types-share-two-taxonomies/55072#55072 Is ok same values in two different taxos but same taxos turn things a mess when filtering.