# Custom Taxonomy Archives on Custom Post type Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Taxonomy specific to a Custom Post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/custom-taxonomy-specific-to-a-custom-post-type)

I have a custom Post type called "**Freebies**" which is displayed differently than rest of the posts (using **single-freebies.php**).
I also have a custom taxonomy called "**resources**" which contains different type of resources like "**icons**", "**templates**" etc...
All my posts in the post type are displayed at **www.example.com/freebies/post-name**

every post in the custom post type has a resource attached to it.
The goodies are also listed at **www.example.com/resources/resource-term**

What I want to do is that the permalink post as **www.example.com/freebies/resource-term/post-name**

resource-term is the resource to which the post belongs....

Till now I have figured out the following "**alternate**" methods

- **Alt. Method 1** - (We are not using the custom post type in this method) Creating a category "freebies" so that the posts type will appear as   **www.example.com/freebies/post-name** and using the resource taxonomy with a slug of freebies such that they are displayed at **www.example.com/freebies/resource-term** or for example **www.example.com/freebies/icons**. However this method will not involve creating the custom post type. This method works provided there is no post with post name same as the resource term to which it belongs otherwise there may be a conflict for instance  **www.example.com/freebies/icons** where icons is the post name with resource same as icons.
- **Alt. Method 2** - Making the slug of the custom post type and the custom taxonomy the same i.e. freebies.
  So the custom post type are displayed at **www.example.com/freebies/post-name** and the resources are displayed at **www.example.com/freebies/resource-name**.
- **Alt Method 3** - Displaying the resources using **www.example.com/freebies/?resources=resource-name** and the freebies at **www.example.com/freebies/resource-name** using the same base or else cancel their display. We can also redirect **www.example.com/resources/resource-name** to **www.example.com/freebies/?resources=resource-name**.
- **Original Method** - I know the process (iguess) but I dont know the htaccess rule for it.The process is as follows:
  Upgrading the the URL 1 level from **www.example.com/freebies/post-name** to **www.example.com/freebies/(resource-name to which the post belongs)/post-name**. I don't know whether dynamic HTACCESS rules exist for modifying and upgrading the URL according to the resource to which the post belongs.

Please, suggest a way to achieve this...any other method is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found Answers here:

- [Permalink rewrite with custom post type and custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55351/permalink-rewrite-with-custom-post-type-and-custom-taxonomy/57586#57586)
- [Custom Taxonomy specific to a Custom Post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/custom-taxonomy-specific-to-a-custom-post-type)