# WordPress Custom URLs

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Based on the link maioman posted, below I have revised this question:

I am having trouble getting a custom post type/taxonomy to work. I want a custom post type of Episodes, and the taxonomy for the custom post type to be Episodes with terms that are generated by the user.

I was able to get

episodes/custom-term-name/ to work. If you go here, it shows all of the posts that are tied to this term.

However if you go to a single post at episodes/custom-term-name/post-title it gives me a 404 page.

```
function episodes() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Episodes', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Episodes', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Episodes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Episodes', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add new episode', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' )
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'episodes/%episode_cat%',
    'with_front'          => false,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'episodes', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'All episodes', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array('title' ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
    'query_var'           => true,
    '_builtin'            => false
);
register_post_type( 'episodes_listing', $args );

 }

add_action( 'init', 'episodes', 0 );

function episodes_taxomony() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Episodes Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Episodes', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Episode Categories', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add new episode', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' )
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'episodes',
    'with_front'                 => false,
    'hierarchical'               => true

);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'query_var'                  => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite
);
register_taxonomy( 'episodes_category', array('episodes_listing'), $args );

}


add_action( 'init', 'episodes_taxomony', 0 );

function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
if ($post->post_type != 'episodes_listing')
    return $link;

if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'episodes_category')) {

    //echo 'This is the '. $link;
    $link = str_replace('%episode_cat%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
return $link;
}
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

In attempts to solve the above issue, I then added in

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
 function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
  $newRules  = array();
  $newRules['episodes/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?custom_post_type_name=$matches[3]'; // my custom structure will always have the post name as the 5th uri segment
$newRules['episodes/(.+)/?$']                = 'index.php?taxonomy_name=$matches[1]'; 

return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

But now 
/episodes/custom-term-name brings me to homepage
/episodes/custom-term-name/post-title brings me to homepage

So, nothing works.

I've tried changing the $matches array number.

Note: in my WP reading settings, I have it set to a static page. This static page is what is showing when I call the mmp_rewrite_rules function.

Comment: use custom taxonomies to get it done!!! here's another quesion that might help you out: [How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post types like base-name/parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types)

Comment: Thank you, this article helped a lot. I still am having an issue, which I posted below

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, at least not in any non-hacky way. You basically want "episodes" to represent 2 different things at the same time, but WP has no way of knowing which is intended for any given path.

I guess you could put some logic at the top of your single post template for your CPT, to check if the "post name" is season-one, season-two etc, and if so handle it accordingly. But it's messy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this post is here [Custom Taxonomy specific to a Custom Post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/custom-taxonomy-specific-to-a-custom-post-type)

I needed change

```
'has_archive'=> 'true'
```

to

```
'has_archive' => 'episodes'
```

and make the capability_type  to post instead of page.

Thanks everyone for the pointers!