# On clicking on the category name the page is redirecting on 404 pge

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, categories, permalinks

I have created a custom post type and added 60 posts and added each post in the category.
I am able to display the post and category on the page and I am using the below code

```
function intelligenceList( $atts ){
  $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'intelligence',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 70, 
        //'orderby' => 'title', 
        //'order' => 'ASC', 
    );  

if(!empty($_REQUEST['keyword'])){
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'intelligence',
  's' => $_REQUEST['keyword'],
  // 'meta_query' => array(
  //   array(
  //     'key' => $_REQUEST['keyword'],
  //     'value' => $_REQUEST['keyword'],
  //     'compare' => 'LIKE'
  //   ),      
  // )
);
}
  $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
   $data ='';
   $data.='<div class="intelligenceList innerBox"><ul>';
   if($loop->have_posts() ) {
        while($loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $tid = $loop->ID;
    $calegoryList = get_the_terms( $tid , 'intelligence_cats' );
    foreach ( $calegoryList as $cat ) {
      $category_link = esc_attr( esc_url( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ) );
      $catname=$cat->name;
        }
             $data .='<li>
                <div class="intelligenceBanner"> <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($tid,'large').'" alt="'.get_the_title($tid).'" class="thumbnailPic">
                </div>
                <div class="intelligenceContent">
                <h6><a href="'.$category_link.'">'.$catname.'</a></h6>
              <h3>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_title($tid),9, '...').'</h3>
              <p>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt($tid),40, '...').'</p>
              <a href="'.get_permalink().'">READ</a>
              </div>
            </li>';
            }
        }
        else{
          $data.='<li>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</li>';
        }
 $data .='</ul></div>';
echo $data;
  //return $postData; 
wp_die(); // it will remove 0.
}
```

Is there any issue with the below code? because when I click on a category then it's redirecting to the 404 pages. I am using below code for categroy

```
foreach ($calegoryList as $cat) {
          $category_link = esc_attr( esc_url( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ) );
          $catname=$cat->name;
         }
      <h6><a href="'.$category_link.'">'.$catname.'</a></h6>
```

I try to reset the permalink setting but still going to the 404 pages.
Would you help me out with how to hyperlink the category name?

Do I need to create the `category.php` page?

**Custom post type**

```
function create_intelligence_cpt() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'intelligences', 'Post Type General Name', 'test' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'intelligence', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'test' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Intelligences', 'Admin Menu text', 'test' ),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'intelligence', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'test' ),
    'archives' => __( 'intelligence Archives', 'test' ),
    'attributes' => __( 'intelligence Attributes', 'test' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent intelligence:', 'test' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Intelligences', 'test' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New intelligence', 'test' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'test' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New intelligence', 'test' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit intelligence', 'test' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update intelligence', 'test' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View intelligence', 'test' ),
    'view_items' => __( 'View intelligences', 'test' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search intelligence', 'test' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'test' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'test' ),
    'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'test' ),
    'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'test' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'test' ),
    'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'test' ),
    'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into intelligence', 'test' ),
    'uploaded_to_testis_item' => __( 'Uploaded to testis intelligence', 'test' ),
    'items_list' => __( 'intelligences list', 'test' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'intelligences list navigation', 'test' ),
    'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter intelligences list', 'test' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'label' => __( 'intelligence', 'test' ),
    'description' => __( '', 'test' ),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-generic',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'testumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats','excerpt'),
    'taxonomies' => array('intelligence_cats'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
  );
  register_post_type( 'intelligence', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_intelligence_cpt', 0 );

/*create category for individual*/
function create_intelligence_taxonomy() {
  register_taxonomy(
        'intelligence_cats',
        'intelligence',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'intelligence' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_intelligence_taxonomy' );
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't need a category template. What do the links it produces look like? Can you adjust that to make a working URL? I'd expect it to be /category/ then the category slug, depending on your permalink setup.

Comment: @Rup, This is the URL after clicking on the category name http://example.com/intelligence/categoryname/

Comment: I'd guess it should be /intelligence_cats/categoryname but I can't see where you code is going wrong. It's not a category but get_category_link should still work, you don't need to use get_term_link instead - especially when you're passing in a term object - and you probably don't need to esc_attr, only esc_url, but that won't make a difference either.

Comment: @Rup, I added a custom post type code in the question. Can you check it once?