# Custom Permalink for Taxonimie and Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

i hope you can help me.
I have an Custom Post Type with an taxonomy and i want to change the permalink of the displayed taxonomy term.

Actually my Urls looks so:
`meineseite.de/posttype/` - archive site
`meineseite.de/posttype/post/` - single post page
`meineseite.de/taxonomy/term` - term page of the taxonomy

and i want that the last url in list looks like this:
**`meineseite.de/posttype/taxonomy/term`** - term page of the taxonomy

**This Setting should be only work for this one custom**

I read already something about the rewrite engine and saw some examples, but i don't get it. Everything i try destroys my website. So i hope that some of you can give me the korrekt answer. Thanks.

Comment: Found the solution here: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/custom-taxonomy-specific-to-a-custom-post-type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/custom-taxonomy-specific-to-a-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**
For my case i only had to add this code to my taxonomy:

```
'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'mypostype-wich-should-be-displayed-before-the-taxonomy', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
        )
```