# url rewriting for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have a post-type Collection with custom-post-type categories.

I want the following url structure: www.baseurl.com/collection/current-category-name/postname

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the rewrite parameter when creating your custom post type:

```
register_post_type( 'example_type',
      array(
          'labels' => array(
              'name' => "Example-Type",
              'singular_name' => "example-type"
          ),
          'public' => true,
          'has_archive' => true,
          'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'the-url-you-want',
      )
  );
}
```

You will need to reset your permalinks for it to take effect as well.

EDIT:

```
function custom_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

Comment: I use `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'the-url-you-want'` to rename the collection, but this doesn't make the url dynamic. This won't put the categorie in the url

Comment: What you could do is put a replaceable string in your slug - for example %category% ('post-type/%category%')and replace it using the post_type_link filter everytime the URL is returned on the website. I changed my answer above with an example. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly that problem to solve as well and found this post from [Diana](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/17048/diana) that solves it:

[Permalink rewrite with custom post type and custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55351/permalink-rewrite-with-custom-post-type-and-custom-taxonomy/55366#55366)