# How can I set up the URL for a category archive for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I'm working on a site `www.site.com` that has an additional post type: `project`.
In registering `project`, I've declared `"taxonomies"=>array("category")` so that I can categorize the essays. Works fine.

Now, the post type archive is at `www.site.com/projects/` as I'd expected, but I can't seem to find a URL for a category archive that fetches only projects.

I'd like it to appear at `www.site.com/projects/category1`.

I've tried every combination of permalink/CPT registration options I could think of, but the best I've gotten was a 404.

I am able to get the results I want if I manually enter `?category_name=category1` in the URL but can't seem to incorporate this into the permalink structure.

Any hints?

Comment: It looks like there is an example of this on [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49141/32110).

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a custom taxonomy?

Comment: @vancoder simplicity, mainly, since Projects will be organized the same way as Posts. If I used a custom taxonomy it would be with the same names and preferably slugs.