# How to change the URL pattern for single post view

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a Custom Post Type registered as "News"

And there are 2 taxonomy being assigned to this Custom Post Type i.e News Category, News Country

Right now if I am previewing the single news page, the URL pattern it generates is `SITE_URL/news/news-title-slug`

I need a custom URL pattern which follows like this
`SITE_URL/{term of News Category}/{term of News Country}/news-title-slug`

I have tried using [add_rewrite_rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), but it is not working.

Comment: Did you already try solutions like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49141/rewriting-a-custom-post-type-permalink-with-taxonomy-term) or [this](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks)?